# Starting a simple HTTPServer as a service on Raspian

Tags: python, bash, service, debian, webserver

Let me begin by saying that this is not a production system and I have no intention of making it one!

I have two scripts:

/home/pi/start.sh (owned by root):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
/usr/bin/python3 poolMonitor.py
```

and
/home/pi/stop.sh (owned by root):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo killproc -k -n poolMonitor.py
```

I have the file /etc/init.d/poolMonitor (owned by root):

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Pool Monitor
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop: 
# Default-Start:     5 
# Default-Stop:      6 
# Starts the Pool Monitor service
### END INIT INFO



start() {
        echo -n "Starting : "
        /home/pi/poolMonitor/start.sh
        return
}

stop() {
        echo -n "Shutting down : "
        /home/pi/poolMonitor/stop.sh
        return
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
    status poolMonitor
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|reload|restart[|probe]"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

I installed the service in init.d like this:

```
sudo update-rc.d poolMonitor defaults
```

I can successfully run (starts and stops the web server and I am able to browse to it):

```
sudo /home/pi/poolMonitor/start.sh
sudo /home/pi/poolMonitor/stop.sh
sudo service poolMonitor stop
sudo service poolMonitor start
```

Note, due to the nature of HTTPServer, start.sh never returns.  I have tried adding an ampersand at the end of the line in the start.sh file:

```
/usr/bin/python3 poolMonitor.py &
```

The problem that I am having is that it does not start after a reboot (whether the ampersand is there or not).

Comment: Looking at the syslog, there is no mention of it trying to start.  I would assume that the system would at least mention that it is attempting to start it

Comment: I tried adding nohup as suggested here (https://superuser.com/questions/338191/start-simplehttpserver-on-boot) before the command, but that caused the pi to not start.  Got it back so that the pi boots and works as before.

Comment: I added it to the crontab:
@reboot /home/pi/poolMonitor/start.sh
and it is working.  Not very elegant, but hey, it works

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for a while and hope that someone has a better solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a systemd service**

To convert the script into a service, create .service file :

```
vi /home/pi/poolMonitor.service
```

Add this structure to poolMonitor.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Pool Monitor 
After=network-online.target
 
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/poolMonitor.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

copy the file into /lib/systemd/system

```
sudo cp /home/pi/poolMonitor.service /lib/systemd/system/
```

Test the service

```
sudo systemctl start poolMonitor.service
```

Stop it using:

```
sudo systemctl stop poolMonitor.service
```

Enable your service to start automatically on reboot by using:

```
sudo systemctl enable poolMonitor.service
```

From now you can use:

```
sudo service poolMonitor status/start/stop
```

Comment: OMG, thank you for the DETAILED explanation. Not sure where I had gone into the weeds, but this sure pulled me out!  Thank you!